# Unable to save edits to simple products in Magento 2.1.1

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, error

I'm in the testing stages of a new magento store. We migrated products from our current store and everything seemed to be working correctly but when trying to update a simple product, the save button won't work. There are no errors and no action of any kind. The button simply doesn't do anything. Save and New, Save and Duplicate and Save and Close all do nothing.

Even when using the dev tools in chrome, it shows no errors or message of any kind.

We've tried other browsers, clearing caches etc. Everything else seems to be working as it should.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands from ssh.
Go to your root folder of magento 2.1 and run.

```
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex
    php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it will work.
Thanks

Comment: unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.